# Postgres/GIS: RULE does not affect all inserts

Tags: postgresql, gis, rule

I have a rule for a table which simply checks if the new entry matches a name and intersects with that matching existing row using `st_intersects` from postgis library.

It seems that only a part are NOT inserted, but most get through this rule. I checked some entries manually after the insert and can confirm the rule should have blocked that insert.

Is something wrong with my RULE?

Table has 3 columns. `id serial`, `name varchar(200)` and `way geometry(Linestring,4326)`

And my RULE is as follows (excerpt from \d names)

```
blockduplicate AS
    ON INSERT TO nameslist
   WHERE (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM nameslist
          WHERE nameslist.name::text = new.name::text AND st_intersects(nameslist.way, new.way) = true)) DO INSTEAD NOTHING
```

This table simply takes a line having a name, and whenever another entry comes in with the same name and intersecting with another existing entry having the same name, it should be blocked. So I have only one entry with this name in the area represented by the geometry field way. After the insert I see plenty of duplicates (name matches and `st_intersects` returns `true` when checking `way` field). Why is my rule not blocking the insert?

**Update:** Is it because I do multiple inserts in one query. I actually insert 12000 entries in one shot with the query `INSERT INTO (a,b,c) VALUES (...),(...),(...),...`
Does PostgreSQL call the RULE for each value? I need to do multiple inserts otherwise it would take months to finish my inserts.

Comment: In PostgreSQL a rule is __not__ a trigger. A rule __rewrites__ the statement and executes the modified statement(s). Hence the question "is the rule called for each value?" does not make sense as the answer is: Depends on the __exact__ rule and the __exact__ statement. Therefore it seems to me, that you have hit the usual weak point on rules: For simple statement (i.e. while your own testing) they work as expected, but not for all statements. The later statements are the ones you don't dream of until you debug the real application and the queries someone _have_ dreamed of. ;-)

Comment: Use triggers not rules and you'll save yourself a lot of confusion and frustration.

Comment: For whatever reason my insertion now seems to work with triggers. But its slooooow. Now takes triple time to insert my data. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, usually you are going to find triggers are cleaner than rules.  Triggers are fired on each insert.  Rules are macros which rewrite your SQL.  There is a time and place for the use of rules but they are certainly an advanced area.

Let's look at what happens with your insert.  Suppose you:

```
  INSERT INTO nameslist
  SELECT * FROM nameslist_import;
```

Your rule will actually rewrite the query into something like:

```
  INSERT INTO nameslist
  SELECT * FROM nameslist_import WHERE not (expression modelled on your rule);
```

Usually it is cleaner here to just write this into your query rather than using a rule to rewrite your query for you.  This allows you to tune exactly what you want to do in each query.  If you want to prevent such data from overlapping, look at exclude constraints if they are applicable or triggers.

Hope this helps.